# create-react-app aborting - ESLINT not found

Tags: reactjs, npm

Attempting to create a new app

```
npx create-react-app my-test-app
```

and getting this error in the console - unsurprisingly the esLint.tgz is 404ing in a browser. How do you get around this?

Running npm 8.13.2 and node 18.4.0

Can't seem to find any similar solutions - tried clearing cache too. Any ideas?

```
npx create-react-app my-test-app

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/eslint/-/eslint-8.4.4.tgz - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@types/eslint@https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/eslint/-/eslint-8.4.4.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-30T19_58_36_128Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed
```

Comment: To solve this error, you can use an older version, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72821705/17973320)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repository error @eslint, see Github: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/61032

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it's not us. It's them.
[NPMJS Status](https://status.npmjs.org/?subscription_confirmed=true)

[tarbells down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqaV2.png)