# @types/eslint v8.4.4 missing from NPM registry

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, types, eslint

##### What to do when the npm registry is missing @types/eslint/-/eslint-8.4.4.tgz ?

I jumped on to run npx create-react-app, however, the output of this is that there is no eslint-8.4.4 found on the npmregistry, looking online they just released 8.4.4 I believe?

Error: '@types/eslint@8.4.4' is not in the npm registry.

I tried to find out how to use eslint-8.4.3 like last week's project used but I can't seem to find a way to create a new react app that specifically uses eslint8.4.3 and does not call on latest which is missing.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `@types/eslint` is directly consumed then you can install version `8.4.3`.

```
npm i -D @types/eslint@8.4.3
```

**For across dependencies:**

```
/* for yarn */
"resolutions": {
  "@types/eslint": "8.4.3"
 }

/* For NPM 8+, use overrides: */

"overrides": {  
  "@types/eslint": "8.4.3"
}
```

If you are trying to create a new project using `create-react-app` as a workaround you can clone and use the below repository.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/main/packages/cra-template/template

or you can use an older version and update dependencies manually.

```
npx create-react-app --scripts-version 4.0.3 app_name
```

npm status regarding this issue: https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/6wr25yb0b2dd

Comment: I think this only works if i have a project existing already? where i would then have a pack-lock to override? currently i have no project and i am using npx-create-react-app to generate that project - would the above still work?

Comment: If you are trying to create a new project using create-react-app as a workaround you can clone and use the below repository.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/main/packages/cra-template/template