# When I type npm start I get an error resolutions in package.json

Tags: reactjs, npm, resolution

I was trying to start a project with 'npx create-react-app'. 
However,
[@types/eslint v8.4.4 missing from NPM registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72821556/types-eslint-v8-4-4-missing-from-npm-registry)  same Error

so i tried **'npx create-react-app@5.0.1 test --template typescript --ignore-existing'**
I solved the problem with that command, but another problem occurred

I typed the **npm start** command in vscode and an error as shown in the picture occurred.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6URf.png)

So I put the following code in package.json.

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.42",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "recoil": "^0.7.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/eslint": "^8.4.3",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.25"
  },
  "overrides": {  
    "@types/eslint": "8.4.3"
  }
}
```

And Installed

1. npm i @types/eslint@8.4.3
2. npm i -D @types/eslint@8.4.3

But I keep getting an error like the picture...

npm v8.5.5
node v16.15.0

Comment: You don't have to remove the content of package.json when adding overrides. You probably replaced everything with what you wrote. You just have to add that override thing before the ending `}`.

Comment: I didn't delete the content of package.json, I just added it at the end

Comment: Can you add your `package.json` as it is in the post? You probably missed a comma or something like that.

Comment: Okay. I uploaded it, please check it!

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Is the file saved? Because in the screenshot that you've attached I am seeing `resolutions` at line 1. Also `resolutions` is for Yarn, for NPM you need `overrides`.

Comment: yes saved. And I'm using npm and since it's 8.5.5 I changed it to `overrides` but I get the same error

Comment: I solved it! There was a package.json file outside the project :(
Thank you for your help!!